# R introduces random x in variables when reading the .csv file. How can I get rid of those?

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I'm trying to plot binary data in R and it seems that when r reads my input file, it introduces "x" before every variable.

My data frame is a longer version of this saved in .csv

```
| Species     | 0.5 |2.5 | 4.5 | 5.5 | 7.5 |...
| Black rat   |     |1   | 0   | 0   | 0   |...
| Norway ra   | 0   |0   | 0   | 0   | 0   |...
| Caribou     | 0   |0   | 0   | 0   | 0   |...
```

And once I import it in R with

```
data <-read.csv("DNA_binaries_flipped.csv")
```

what I get from

```
head(data) #Check that data looks correct
```

is

```
     Species X0.5 X2.5 X4.5 
1  Black rat    0    1    0
2 Norway rat    0    0    0
3    Caribou    0    0    0
```

I late plot the data and obviously the "X" is still there. How can I get rid of this

Here's a photo of the complete plot

[image: complete plot]

I tried to restart R and create a new input file

Comment: This is obviously my first stack overflow post as tables didn't show up properly

Comment: Does your CSV file not have a header row that gives the column names? Column names in R are treated like variable names and should not start with numbers. If you need to have the names be numbers, you can use `check.names=FALSE` in `read.csv` but then you have to be careful when you use those column names later.

Comment: Thank you. This solves my issue. Originally I had a header but the figure I'm trying to get (presence/absence PCR results) was hard to get with my original data fram so I played around with it and got here. Anyway all is well  now. Didn't realize R is upset with numbers, but then again have never been in this scenario before where numbers are my headers

Answer (score 0):

R does not like to use numbers for column names in data frames, or for vectors in general.

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/make.names.html

> A syntactically valid name consists of letters, numbers and
> the dot or underline characters and starts with a letter or the dot
> not followed by a number. Names such as ".2way" are not valid, and
> neither are the reserved words.
>
> The definition of a letter depends on the current locale, but only
> ASCII digits are considered to be digits.
>
> The character "X" is prepended if necessary. All invalid characters
> are translated to ".". A missing value is translated to "NA". Names
> which match R keywords have a dot appended to them. Duplicated values
> are altered by make.unique.

It is possible to create a data frame with names that are not syntactically valid, but this can lead to unexpected behaviors so is generally avoided.

I'd suggest removing the `X` from your variable names once you have converted them to variable values and prior to plotting, e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(row = 1:3, X1 = 1:3, X2.3 = 2:4) %>%
  pivot_longer(-row) %>%
  mutate(name = str_sub(name, start = 2)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(row, name, fill = as.character(value))) +
  geom_tile()
```

[image]